# Is there a way to get internal data from php?

Tags: php, debugging, function, variables

I know there are PHP debugging tools available, but I'm curious about doing something like this myself.

Is there a way to obtain the data that is being processed by PHP for debugging purposes? For example, without having to change the code of my PHP application, is there some way, when I run a function, I can see what variables exist within that function, what called that function, what the return value was etc?

The solution doesn't specifically doesn't need to be in PHP, ie this could be somethig that is written in C etc

Comment: Everyone has kind of missed the point where in the first line I said "I know there are PHP debugging tools available, but I'm curious about doing something like this myself." - anyway, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Well, may I suggest you look into adding [firePHP](http://firephp.org/) to your code.  FirePHP has 2 components, a server side component, and a browser component for firefox, it uses the firebug addon.  Once installed properly you can do things like FB::Log($variable) and you will see this information inside of the log portion of firebug, when you click on it, it shows the entire variable broken out.   Also if you were to install the error handler, when you get a caught exception, you are able to see the entire stack trace of how this exception was invoked.

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

try PHP xdebug module - http://xdebug.org/
u can log the debugging info,
or output as HTML

changes might required to initiate xdebug

Answer (score 0):

You can use some introspective functions like [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but these will only get you so far. To gather *any* kind of information, you would need to hook into PHP itself, which you would most likely do with an extension written in C. I'd suggest you check out one of the existing debuggers to see how they do it, for example [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/download.php).